# Compiling GSL odeiv2 with g++

Tags: gcc, g++, gsl

I'm attempting to compile the example code relating to the ODE solver, `gsl/gsl_odeiv2`, using g++. The code below is from their website :

`http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/ODE-Example-programs.html`

and compiles fine under gcc, but g++ throws the error

`invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int (*)(double, const double*, double*, double*,
void*)' [-fpermissive]`

in the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>

int func (double t, const double y[], double f[], void *params)
{
    double mu = *(double *)params;
    f[0] = y[1];
    f[1] = -y[0] - mu*y[1]*(y[0]*y[0] - 1);
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}


int * jac;

int main ()
{
    double mu = 10;
    gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {func, jac, 2, &mu};

    gsl_odeiv2_driver * d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45, 1e-6, 1e-6, 0.0);
    int i;
    double t = 0.0, t1 = 100.0;
    double y[2] = { 1.0, 0.0 };

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        double ti = i * t1 / 100.0;
        int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply (d, &t, ti, y);

        if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf ("error, return value=%d\n", status);
            break;
        }

        printf ("%.5e %.5e %.5e\n", t, y[0], y[1]);
    }

    gsl_odeiv2_driver_free (d);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is given on the line

`gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {func, jac, 2, &mu};`

Any help in solving this issue would be fantastic. I'm hoping to include some stdlib elements, hence wanting to compile it as C++. Also, if I can get it to compile with g++-4.7, I could more easily multithread it using C++11's additions to the language. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have some problems with Jacobian. In your particular case you could just use NULL instead of jac in the definition of your system, i.e.

```
gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {func, NULL, 2, &mu};
```

In general you Jacobian must be a function with particular entries - see gsl manual - that is why your compiler is complaining.

Also, you may want to link the gsl library manually:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lgsl
```

if you are on a linux system.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem. I declared a Jacobian as a function of the relevant arguments that did nothing, but I'll go with NULL next time, as it's cleaner.